# How to fix socket IO Exception in Android 9.0?

Tags: socket.io, android-9.0-pie

I am using java.net.Socket for socket communication.I have tried the solution for network-security-config.xml file which allow localhost for socket communication.

My code snippet is below :

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.1", "5000");
```

And my network-security-config.xml file is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://192.168.1.1:5000</domain>
</domain-config>
```

I have also tried with below snippet

```
1) Replace <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://192.168.1.1:5000</domain> to <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://localhost:5000</domain>

2) Replace <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://192.168.1.1:5000</domain> to <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
```

But none of the above solution works. May Be I missed something.

If any one have experience for this problem. Please provide solution.

Thanks for your help.